# Unable to use Apache Archiva as Mirror

Tags: maven-2, repository, archiva

I think this was supposed to be a simple task, but I've been unable to accomplish it.

I've set an archiva repository as this:

- 2 Internal Maven1 repos (old projects)
- 1 Internal Maven2 repo
- 7 Remote repos (central, java.net, jboss.org, etc.)

For each internal repo I've created a proxy connection with each remote repo.

I've added a new mirror to my settings.xml file as explained in the archiva documentation:

```
<mirror>
  <id>archiva.default</id>
  <url>http://repo.mycompany.com:8080/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

When I try building a simple project with one dependency from some of the remote repositories, no artifacts are downloaded. Why?!?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sure you're using the correct settings file? Use "mvn -s settings.xml" to be sure.

Comment: @Mark: yes
@Pascal: it only says that mvn failed to get the .jar files from the repository. I don't see anything useful on archiva.
So, is this configuration fine?
I checked if the archiva has connection to this repos and it does.

Comment: when you say "each internal" repository, you should only need to connect the main internal repo to the remotes, not all the internal ones. Not sure what you mean by "archiva has connection" - try downloading a requested URL directly from Archiva. The configuration looks fine. You can also change Archiva's log4j to turn up proxy logging if that might help.

Comment: @Brett oh! don't I need to create a Proxy connector between each internal and remote repository? With "archiva has connection" I meant to say that I was able to download a jar from the remote repositories. The problem is that the "main" repository is Maven1 and is used by THE project. Then, there's the M2 repository, which is used for "experimental" projects. Maybe only the main repository is able to proxy?

Comment: Is it because the remote artifact is cached in your local repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Archiva doesn't assign repositories any special roles. You make requests to specific managed repository from Maven (so from your settings, `internal`), and it will serve what is in there, or proxy it from remote repositories that have been connected by a proxy connector. By default, that is just Central - adding a new remote repository has no effect until it is connected to a managed repository by a proxy connector.

What you probably want to do is add a proxy connector on the internal repo to the remote repositories in question. Consider setting the whitelist too so that it is more effecient.

You may also want to set up a repository group that spans all the managed repositories (both maven 1 and maven 2) for use from a single URL.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I get to work and see if it works.

Comment: Your solution works. I've got mvn to get the artifacts using a group. But, it's using the Maven1 repository. Anyway, it works, so that's it. I hope to get rid of the M1 stuff sooner than later.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem with Archiva 2, for me the solution was to give the "Global Repository Observer" role to the Guest user.